# Expression for "someone who's clueless of their surroundings"?

Tags: idioms, expressions, popular-refrains

What is an expression or saying you could use to describe someone that is totally clueless of their surroundings?

Comment: What surroundings? What's wrong with 'clueless'?

Comment: @Mitch, 'clueless' would be fine if I wanted to simply convey the meaning, but I'm not looking to merely convey the meaning--I want to colorfully paint out the meaning with a flair.

Comment: Oh, you didn't make that obvious. What suggestions from a thesaurus have you found?

Comment: If you're looking for "flair", then this question is much better suited for [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Zairja, thanks! I had no idea about Writer's Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Oblivious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/oblivious)**

> not aware of or not noticing something, esp. what is happening around you: *She was often oblivious to the potential consequences of her actions*.

The slang term **[zoned out](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zoned%20out)** could also be used

> Spaced out, stoned, unaware, oblivious, unconscious, drugged, narcotized. Derived from the 70's phrase "lost in the ozone", which led to the related terms "ozoned", "zoned", and "zoned out". *I got kinda zoned out listening to Green Day and forgot to finish my term paper.*

SUPPLEMENT: In light of the comment, what about:

> in a daze
>
> out to lunch
>
> without a clue
>
> in zombieland
>
> head in the clouds
>
> walking on air
>
> playing without a full deck
>
> spaced out
>
> in lala land
>
> spacey [no, that's just a term or synonym]
>
> in his own world

It's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know of any expressions or sayings rather than terms/synonyms?

Comment: Thanks! "Head in the clouds" is just the type I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

["Away with the fairies."](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/away_with_the_fairies)
"In a [dwam](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dwam)." (Scottish)

Comment: Nice. I've never heard of either one of those, but they both fit the bill.